# Why is Mavericks Server reporting ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi?

Tags: django, python-2.7, osx-mavericks

Why am I getting these errors with OS X Server 3?

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=1455): Target WSGI script \   
   '/Users/iainhouston/DjangoSites/mysite/mysite/site.wsgi' \  
   cannot be loaded as Python module.

 mod_wsgi (pid=1455): Exception occurred processing WSGI script \  
 '/Users/iainhouston/DjangoSites/mysite/mysite/site.wsgi'.

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/iainhouston/DjangoSites/mysite/mysite/site.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

even though `django.core.wsgi` exists:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 iainhouston  _www   394B  4 Sep 17:23 \  
/Users/iainhouston/Library/django-trunk/django/core/wsgi.py
```

Similar questions don't address this error on OS X Server 3.

### Background

#### Using the Django sample `mysite` app

I confirmed that the Server's sample is working using `python manage.py run server`
=> `"Django version 1.8.dev20140904142332`

#### Installing as a web app in OS X Server 3 on Mavericks

I confirmed that sample web app works
=> "`... executed via the webapp.plist(8) mechanism. Python version 2.7.5 running mod_wsgi.`"

`mod_wsgi.so` seems to be compatible with Mavericks Python:

```
otool -L /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot \
  /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so =>             
  ....  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python \
  (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.5)`   
  ...
```

Python 2.7 paths seem correct:

```
>>> print django.__file__
/Users/iainhouston/Library/django-trunk/django/__init__.pyc
```

from: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django.pth`
=> `/Users/iainhouston/Library/django-trunk/`

com.iainhouston.django.wsgi.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /django /Users/iainhouston/DjangoSites/mysite/mysite/site.wsgi
```

Comment: Does the Apache user have rights to see files in your personal home directory? That's a peculiar place to install things. You should put the files somewhere central and use a virtualenv.

Comment: You're right Daniel. It is peculiar. I'm at the 'proof of concept' stage with Django

Comment: Migrating Development Django sites to Production. I wanted to explore a 'proof of concept' integrating OS X Server's Apache with Django before committing to installing Django system-wide on this production server. Drupal staging sites running in this user space already so OS permissions OK but Apache Directory permissions may be the issue here but probably also with system-wide Django. Subsequently I need to understand the implications of virtualenvs for managing  production server.